# Measure DOM after React.Suspense children are rendered

Tags: reactjs

Look at the following code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, lazy, Suspense } from 'react';

const LazyLoadedComponent = lazy(() => import('path/to/component'));

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Initialization depends on lazy element DOM measurments,
    // i.e. their heights
    initScrollPosition();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading...">
      {/* Other elements */}
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
      <LazyLoadedComponent />
      {/* Other elements */}
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

When `initScrollPosition` is called, probably `LazyLoadedComponent` is not fetched yet and `Suspense` fallback is shown. In this case, all DOM measurements inside `initScrollPosition` are done based on the fallback of `Suspense` and not the actual contents, so scroll position is not initialized as expected.

Is there any solution to this problem other than dealing with callback refs or setting some flags in `cDM/useEffect` call of `LazyLoadedComponent`?

*Note: Waiting for dynamic import to resolve and then initializing the scroll position doesn't work too, because when dynamic import resolves, the elements are not rendered yet and measurements are still not as expected.*

Comment: There is no other solution... Only if  you make some prediction as hardcoded code

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I think of is with CSS, hide the components until you got your measurements.

```
// inner use of display: block/none ; and/or visibility: visible/hidden
<Display isDisplayed={areMeasuresAvailabale}>
  <LazyComponent />
</Display>;
```